# The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, spring, swing

Hi am facing issue with below error in eclipse please help to resolve this issue.

**Error message**

***The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files***

I imported the jar file (org.springframework.context-3.0.4.RELEASE) even then am facing this issue.

**see below code**( where am getting issue at line ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");)

```
    package com.csp.test.document;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    import com.csp.model.Document;
    import com.csp.service.DocumentService;

    public class DocumentTest {

        @Test
        public void testGetDocument() {
            ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "applicationContext.xml");

            DocumentService documentService = (DocumentService) appCtx
                    .getBean("documentService");

            Document doc = documentService.getDocument(1);

            String status = null;

            if (doc != null) {
                status = documentService.saveDocument(doc);
            } else {
                System.out.println("error in retreiving document");
            }

            assertEquals("Success Status", "SUCCESS", status);

        }

    }
```

Comment: this jar needs to be present in the dependencies.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you aren't using maven (or any other dependency management tool, for that matter), you should add `spring-context` dependencies manually, which are `spring-beans`, `spring-core`, `spring-aop` and `spring-expression`, of course each of them have their own dependencies either (Transitive Dependency). By the way, `BeansException` is part of `spring-beans` module

Comment: Thank you :) as you said I have download (spring-beans-3.1.xsd download) jar and its worked for me......

Comment: Your welocome. for better dependency management, i recommend to use  maven

Comment: If you are maven user then upgrade your version >= 4.0.0

Comment: Okay now I saw when this exception is raised, can you give the reason like what exactly calls `BeansException`

Answer (score 6):

May be you are missing org.springframework.beans-3.0.4.RELEASE   jar

Comment: exactly! this jar needs to be present in the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I've managed to resolve the issue.... I use the following pattern: the program and the results without error

Version:
3.0.4.RELEASE

Then select -> Maven-> Update Project

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Look around, it's English site. For now, I've translated the post in English. Please post your questions, answers and comments in English.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have problems with *org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware*
Adding this dependency in pom from maven repository solve my problem.

*<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>*
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are missing the Spring Beans dependency. If you are using Maven, add the Spring Beans dependency to your **pom.xml** file.

An example would be as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You can search for the latest version of Spring Beans from the Maven Repository website: https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project>Select Maven>Update Project>Select your project name>Ok

This resolved my error.