# Error appeared in Spring

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring.

I installed Eclipse and downloaded Spring from http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/

Then, I added external jar files in downloaded Spring folder.

However, I got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    The constructor ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String) refers to the missing type BeansException
    The method getBean(String) is undefined for the type ApplicationContext
    at org.gontuseries.springcore.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:11)

The attached figure shows Eclipse, including errors, including library files, programming files.

Can you please help?

Thanks a lot.

Eclipse errors: http://postimg.org/image/ownlk80t9/

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425472/the-type-org-springframework-beans-beansexception-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indi)

Answer (score -2):

[This exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27425472/1207019) is very similar to your problem and should give you the solution.

Usually, [such a redundant question should be flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). As this is your first one, there is no problem.

Comment: *"As this is your first one, it will be fine."* any link to the guideline mentioning this "rule"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I included the reference. Thanks also the downvotes, I admit my answer is a bit rough: a comment would have been better. But I was thinking to the section *"If I can, should I (vote to) close the question?"* in the meta stackechange.

Comment: The section *Should I flag it for moderator attention?* is also interesting: it suggest that new questions shouldn't be flagged directly.

Comment: It mentioned that I should add spring-context dependencies manually, which are spring-beans, spring-core, spring-aop and spring-expression. Where can I download all this stuff? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Over here](http://mvnrepository.com/tags/spring), just follow the links to get the jars for the appropriate dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
Can I download all jar files efficiently instead of clicking one by one?

Comment: For that the simplest solution is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but this is another story.

Comment: I have included all the jar files in "http://mvnrepository.com/tags/spring"  but the error appears:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The type org.springframework.beans.BeansException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
 The constructor ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String) refers to the missing type BeansException
 The method getBean(String) is undefined for the type ApplicationContext at org.gontuseries.springcore.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:11)

Comment: I checked it in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425472/the-type-org-springframework-beans-beansexception-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indi". It suggests to include 4 files:spring-beans, spring-core, spring-aop and spring-expression. My included files are spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar and spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar. However, the error still appears. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: In the Eclipse screenshot linked in your question, there where unresolved compilation problems. With the JAR files you included in your classpath, it is unlikely that you still have spring-context missing. What are the remaining compilation problems ?

Comment: Not to be rude, you should do it by yourself. This is simple : take the main package (org.springframework.beans), google gives you the answer (spring-bean).

Comment: @Frankie if you have further problem not directly related to your original question ask a new one, don't add comments nobody will read.